# French language comes up before English language site for site: search on English version of Google

Tags: google, canonical-url, language, hreflang

Our homepage has two versions:

```
https://www.construct.net/fr
https://www.construct.net/en
```

The first being in French, the second English.  Both versions have been online for many weeks.

Searching on Google or Bing from their .FR domains yields no results for the French version of the page.  Yet doing a `site:construct.net` on the English version of Google returns:

[image]

**Meta tags on French page:**

```
<html lang="fr-FR">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.construct.net/fr" />
<meta rel="alternate" href="https://www.construct.net/fr" hreflang="fr" />
<meta rel="alternate" href="https://www.construct.net/en" hreflang="en" />
<meta rel="alternate" href="https://www.construct.net/en-us" hreflang="en-US" />
```

**Meta tags on English page:**

```
<html lang="en-US">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.construct.net/en" />
<meta rel="alternate" href="https://www.construct.net/en" hreflang="en" />
<meta rel="alternate" href="https://www.construct.net/fr" hreflang="fr" />
<meta rel="alternate" href="https://www.construct.net/fr-fr" hreflang="fr-FR" />
```

My questions are:

- Have I correctly set up the meta tags?
- If not should Google even be showing the French alternative version in the English results?
- Why is the French version showing up higher than the English homepage in the above results?

Comment: Site: search results are special beasts. The order often doesn't make sense.  Does this happen for any real English language queries as well?

Comment: "no results for the French version of **the page**." - By "the page" are you literally referring to just the home page? A quick browse of your site appears to show very little actual French-language content. Most of the `/fr/...` URLs have English content (with French navigation) - essentially _duplicating_ the `/en/...` page - and do not have `hreflang` tags. So, currently, it looks like a predominantly English-language site with a bunch of "duplicate content"?

Comment: @MrWhite some pages are available in French, these ones are marked correctly I believe in their meta tags as such.  EG:

https://www.construct.net/fr  
https://www.construct.net/fr/make-games/games-editor  
https://www.construct.net/fr/make-games/buy-construct-3  
https://www.construct.net/fr/make-games/faq

If you browse a page that's not translated, EG: https://www.construct.net/fr/make-games/education it will keep the fr in the URL so that it loads French on other pages if available but shows English content (canonical will point to /en page)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions:

- If you do not have localized country-specific versions of your site live at the `https://www.construct.net/en-us` and `https://www.construct.net/fr-fr` URLs, then remove those lines. By just having `en` and `fr`, they will act [as a catchall for all language regions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).
- Google shouldn't be showing the French version in normal English results, but it may show them in `site:` results like in your example. Like Stephen mentioned, are you seeing the French version appear for any natural English language queries? If the French version does not appear for natural English language queries, then your site is configured properly. Google's `site:` queries are a tool to show all the URLs that Google has indexed on your domain, so it makes sense that they would include foreign language URLs - think of `site:` as a debugging/technical tool rather than a tool that is reflective of normal queries.
- For `site:` queries, there is no natural language that the search engine can read to understand the user's intent. Therefore the results are presented in an order that may not make much sense, and may include results that would not be presented to a real user searching with a normal language query - this is expected behavior. Because effectively zero real users arrive on a site by searching with a `site:` query, the quirkiness of the `site:` query will not affect your actual SERP presence, so is a non-issue.